# Jboss EAP-7.X Automation

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I want to automate application deployment on top of jboss eap 7 using puppet or ansible. If I manually configure the application related configuration through jboss management console and copy the standalone file to perform automation in another box will it work or do I need to take anyother approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command-line interface tool `jboss-cli.sh` to automate configuration changes, including application deployment. You will need your Standalone or DomainController to be started for that to work.

The following shell command should deploy an application :

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c 'deploy /path/to/application.war'
```

This assumes a running Standalone or DomainController available at the default address (localhost:8090), if you use another port for your management interface you will want to specify the `--controller=host:port` option or a `-Djboss.cli.config=/path/to/jboss-cli.xml` where the `jboss-cli.xml` should specify the connection settings.

You can check `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --help` for more information on the command-line interface tool itself, and launching the tool without a command parameter will lead you to an interactive shell where the `help` command and the smart autocompletion can help you discover the features of the tool.

Comment: So my question will be any changes done through management console are captured on the standalone file

Comment: Yes, configuration changes through either the web console or the CLI will both lead to a modified standalone.xml. You could modify the standalone.xml directly yourself but this isn't recommended as it is prone to error, while the web console doesn't let you do errors and the CLI will raise an error if you do one rather than put the configuration in an incorrect state